# Joins with 4 tables returns a row for every entry in the fourth table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 4 tables, UnitsCoreDetails, CustomersTable, CustomerSiteTable, CustomerDetailsTable
[image]

I need to retrieve the Unit name (From UnitCoreDetails), customerName (From CustomersTable) and CustomerContact (From CustomerDetailsTable)
using the serial number.

I have tried many different joins, inner, outer, left and right and many different combinations but I always end up with a row of data for every entry in the `CustomerDetailsTable`.

Can anyone help with the syntax of this please or tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Select distinct 
    Serial, Model, Manufacturer, Customer, c.CustomerName, cd.CustomerContact
From 
    UnitCoreDetails u 
Left Join 
    CustomersTable c 
ON
    c.CustomerID=u.Customer 
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerSiteTable cs 
ON 
    c.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID  
INNER JOIN 
    CustomerDetailsTable cd 
ON 
    cs.CustomerSiteID=cd.CustomerSiteID 
WHERE 
    u.Serial = 'test'
```

Comment: `RIGHT OUTER JOIN CustomerDetailsTable` is your problem (or at lest one of them, anyway). Make it an INNER join.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I tried that but it still gives me the same result.

Comment: @redned - try doing just inner joins.  It sounds like doing outer joins will bring back more than you need.  I'd probably look at joining CustomerDetailsTable to CustomerSiteTable to CustomersTable to UnitCoreTable.  If you are bringing back multiple rows still then it is a data issue.  Meaning you have records in the CustomerDetailsTable that relate to your UnitCoreDetails...

Comment: Then youve got data problems.  We'll need to see sample data that can reproduce your results.

Comment: Do you need the `CustomerDetailsTable` to get `CustomerContact` since it is also in the `UnitCoreDetails` table according to your diagram?

Comment: Can a given customer have multiple rows in the `CustomerDetailsTable`?

Comment: Your joins are all over the place, LEFT JOIN then INNER JOIN then RIGHT JOIN, Pick a side and then stick to it. When you do an Outer join and then an Inner join it filters out all the non matching rows that you brought forward from your last outer join. Always do your Inner joins 1st and then Lefts or Right joins and pick a side LEFT and then Right join kinda kills the purpose.

Comment: @M.Ali - Thanks for the tip on the order. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
SELECT  Serial
      , Model   
      , Manufacturer
      , Customer
      , CustomerName
      , CustomerContact
FROM 
 (
    Select  Serial
          , Model   
          , Manufacturer
          , Customer
          , c.CustomerName
          , cd.CustomerContact
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Serial ORDER BY Serial) rn
    From        UnitCoreDetails      u 
    INNER JOIN  CustomersTable       c      ON c.CustomerID=u.Customer 
    INNER JOIN  CustomerSiteTable    cs     ON c.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID  
    INNER JOIN  CustomerDetailsTable cd     ON cs.CustomerSiteID=cd.CustomerSiteID 
    WHERE u.Serial = 'test' 
  )Q
WHERE rn = 1
```